# Drawing map with geopandas library for a continent, but the data points contains whole world

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, geospatial, geopandas

I have got data set of meteorites which were found with latitude and longitude information. I almost have 30,000 data points from all around the world. But I would like to plot the map of only one continent, for example "South America" by using geopandas library.

I am using 'naturalearth_lowres' default map of geopandas. From that world map, I filtered South America. My data which is called **mod_data_geo** consists geometry type data, Point(longitute, latitude).

Data Set looks like that:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oetNa.png]

My code:

```
mod_data_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(mod_data, geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(mod_data['long'], mod_data['lat']))

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

countries = world[world['continent'] == "South America"]

axis = countries.plot(color = 'Lightblue', edgecolor = 'black', figsize=(15,15))

mod_data_geo.plot(ax=axis, markersize = 1, color  = 'purple' )
```

Map that I plotted:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsnYK.png]

How can I filter data of meteorites inside mod_data_geo dataframe with Geopandas library or any other tool, in order to see only meteorites found over the South Africa continent only?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please do not post data, code, error messages as images. Paste the text directly here on SO.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Mr. T's comment is referencing the stack overflow [policy against posting images of code, data, or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, try to create a [mre]. You're almost there - great job helping us out with the code to reproduce the shapefile! Constructing a new dataset with a few points, e.g. `mod_data_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy([-10, 60, -120], [-40, 10, 45]))` would get you most of the way there :)

Answer (score 0):

Three ways - crop the image, filter the points with a bounding box, or filter the points by checking whether they're inside the country shapes.

#### Crop the image

If you'd like the points to extend to the edge of the image, but simply to limit the image extent, you can simply set the x and y limits on the matplotlib axis:

```py
axis = countries.plot(color = 'Lightblue', edgecolor = 'black', figsize=(15,15))
orig_extent = axis.get_extent()
mod_data_geo.plot(ax=axis, markersize = 1, color  = 'purple' )
axis.set_extent(*orig_extent)
```

#### Filter to a bounding box

The first approach is nice in that it retains all the data that can fit within your plot. But it's not super efficient, as matplotlib has to filter the data for you based on whether it will appear in the image. A faster approach could filter the data first; note that the data will no longer go to the edge of the image.

First find a bounding box around the countries:

```py
In [6]: bounds = countries.bounds.agg({'minx': 'min', 'miny': 'min', 'maxx': 'max', 'maxy': 'max'})

In [7]: bounds
Out[7]:
minx   -81.410943
miny   -55.611830
maxx   -34.729993
maxy    12.437303
dtype: float64
```

Then you can filter the data based on these bounds:

```py
In [8]: mod_data_filtered = mod_data_geo[(
   ...:     (mod_data_geo.lat >= bounds.miny)
   ...:     (mod_data_geo.lat <= bounds.maxy)
   ...:     (mod_data_geo.long >= bounds.minx)
   ...:     (mod_data_geo.long <= bounds.maxx)
   ...: )]
```

Now you can plot with `mod_data_filtered`.

Note that you could set the extent of the plot to the bounding box, though this will get a bit tight.

#### Filter with country shapes

If you'd like to filter the data to being within one of the countries rather than just cropping the data to the bounding box, you could use [`geopandas.GeoSeries.contains`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.contains.html).

First, dissolve the data to get a single shape for South America:

```py
In [8]: south_america = countries.dissolve()

In [9]: south_america
Out[9]:
                                            geometry   pop_est      continent       name iso_a3  gdp_md_est
0  MULTIPOLYGON (((-57.75000 -51.55000, -58.05000...  44293293  South America  Argentina    ARG    879400.0
```

Then, filter the points to those within the shape:

```py
In [10]: mod_data_filtered = mod_data_geo[south_america.contains(mod_data_geo)]
```

Comment: Michael, thank you for your explanation. I do not understand how to import  into the bounds these values: minx = -81.410943, miny = -55.611830, maxx   -34.729993, maxy    12.437303. Can you explain me a little bit more? Also countries inside the bounds command equal to the continent?

Comment: the bounds command should work directly on the `countries` GeoDataFrame you're working with. [`bounds`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.bounds.html) is a geopandas spatial directive that will get the bounding box for each country, which I then aggregated with min/max. It looks like I could have also just used [`countries.total_bounds`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.total_bounds.html) too.

Comment: oh maybe you're confused about the `In [7]: bounds`, `Out[7]: ...` part? That's just an ipython prompt. You can ignore the `Out` output fields and just use the assignment statements. I was just showing you what happens at each step.

Comment: I got this error:  "AttributeError: '-81.410943' is not a valid function for 'Series' object". 
                         
    bounds = countries.bounds.agg({'minx': '-81.410943', 'miny': '-55.611830', 'maxx': '-34.729993', 'maxy': '12.437303'})

    mod_data_filtered = mod_data_geo[((mod_data_geo.lat >= bounds.miny), 
    (mod_data_geo.lat <= bounds.maxy), (mod_data_geo.long >= bounds.minx), 
    (mod_data_geo.long <= bounds.maxx))]

Comment: Oh yes, in [7], I got confused. And that is why an error raised on the Colab. As I wrote above.

Comment: I also put comma in mod_data_filtered between parantheses, is it also false for part [8]?

Comment: I got this error now:
"DataFrame constructor called with incompatible data and dtype: 'float' object is not callable"

Inside dictionary 'minx' = 'number', I used 'minx' = float. After that error type changed. But I still have problem with bounds part.

Comment: ok - the code I wrote can literally be run without modification. don't do this: `bounds = countries.bounds.agg({'minx': '-81.410943', 'miny': '-55.611830', 'maxx': '-34.729993', 'maxy': '12.437303'})`. do this: `countries.bounds.agg({'minx': 'min', 'miny': 'min', 'maxx': 'max', 'maxy': 'max'})
`. I tested my code and it works - there aren't any placeholders in there.